# Access method group within expression tree

Tags: c#, expression-trees, linq-expressions

I am trying to write an expression tree that can subscribe to an event given by `EventInfo` with a method given by `MethodInfo`. The expression tree should compile into an `Action<object, object>` where the parameters are the event source object and the subscribing object. The EventInfo and MethodInfos are guaranteed to be compatible.

Here is what I have so far:

```
// Given the following
object Source = /**/;           // the object that will fire an event
EventInfo SourceEvent = /**/;   // the event that will be fired
object Target = /**/;           // the object that will subscribe to the event
MethodInfo TargetMethod = /**/; // the method that will react to the event

// setting up objects involved
var sourceParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "source");
var targetParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "target");
var sourceParamCast = Expression.Convert(sourceParam, SourceEvent.DeclaringType);
var targetParamCast = Expression.Convert(targetParam, TargetMethod.DeclaringType);

// Get subscribing method group. This is where things fail
var targetMethodRef = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(targetParamCast, TargetMethod);
// Subscribe to the event
var addMethodCall = Expression.Call(sourceParamCast, SourceEvent.AddMethod, targetMethodRef);

var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Action<object, object>>(addMethodCall, sourceParam, targetParam);
var subscriptionAction = lambda.Compile();

// And then later, subscribe to the event
subscriptionAction(Source, Target);
```

At the call to `MakeMemberAccess` I get the following exception:

> ArgumentException: Member 'void theMethodName()' not field or property

The goal here is for `targetMethodRef` to essentially represent what would appear on the right side of `+=` when subscribing to an event with a method.

TLDR: How do I create an expression for passing a method group on an object as a parameter to a function call within an expression tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be this. The complexity here is that you have to create a delegate inside the lambda method with the `CreateDelegate`. Sadly it doesn't seem possible to create an open delegate (a delegate without the `target`) to be compiled inside the lambda method and then "close" it inside the lambda method when the lambda method is executed. Or at least I don't know how to do it. `CreateDelegate` sadly is a little slow.

```
static Action<object, object> MakeFunc(EventInfo sourceEvent, MethodInfo targetMethod)
{
    // setting up objects involved
    var sourceParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "source");
    var targetParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "target");
    var sourceParamCast = Expression.Convert(sourceParam, sourceEvent.DeclaringType);
    var targetParamCast = Expression.Convert(targetParam, targetMethod.DeclaringType);
    var createDelegate = typeof(Delegate).GetMethod(nameof(Delegate.CreateDelegate), BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public, null, new[] { typeof(Type), typeof(object), typeof(MethodInfo) }, null);

    // Create a delegate of type sourceEvent.EventHandlerType
    var createDelegateCall = Expression.Call(createDelegate, Expression.Constant(sourceEvent.EventHandlerType), targetParam, Expression.Constant(targetMethod));

    // Cast the Delegate to its real type
    var delegateCast = Expression.Convert(createDelegateCall, sourceEvent.EventHandlerType);

    // Subscribe to the event
    var addMethodCall = Expression.Call(sourceParamCast, sourceEvent.AddMethod, delegateCast);

    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Action<object, object>>(addMethodCall, sourceParam, targetParam);
    var subscriptionAction = lambda.Compile();

    return subscriptionAction;
}
```

Mmmh... can be done by calling the delegate constructor. Built by trial (haven't found much documentation about this):

```
static Action<object, object> MakeFunc(EventInfo sourceEvent, MethodInfo targetMethod)
{
    // setting up objects involved
    var sourceParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "source");
    var targetParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "target");
    var sourceParamCast = Expression.Convert(sourceParam, sourceEvent.DeclaringType);
    var targetParamCast = Expression.Convert(targetParam, targetMethod.DeclaringType);

    ConstructorInfo delegateContructror = sourceEvent.EventHandlerType.GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public, null, new[] { typeof(object), typeof(IntPtr) }, null);
    IntPtr fp = targetMethod.MethodHandle.GetFunctionPointer();

    // create the delegate
    var newDelegate = Expression.New(delegateContructror, targetParam, Expression.Constant(fp));

    // Subscribe to the event
    var addMethodCall = Expression.Call(sourceParamCast, sourceEvent.AddMethod, newDelegate);

    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Action<object, object>>(addMethodCall, sourceParam, targetParam);
    var subscriptionAction = lambda.Compile();

    return subscriptionAction;
}
```

`Delegate`s have a constructor with two parameters, the target `object` and a `IntPtr` that is the native function pointer to the method. It is normally used by the CIL with the `ldftn`/`ldvirtftn`, but the `.MethodHandle.GetFunctionPointer()` is the same "thing". So we call this constructor inside the lambda expression we build.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, part of the point of writing this using expression trees is to try and avoid the `CreateDelegate` call for every target instance. I don't mind expression compilation or `CreateDelegate` calls for every (EventInfo, MethodInfo) pair but doing so for every instance is just too expensive.

Comment: @DeanJohnson Added a second variant without the CreateDelegate

Comment: @DeanJohnson While undocumented, there is at least a case in Microsoft code [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/Util/FastDelegateCreator.cs,29) where they do the same: call a delegate constructor with the result of `GetFunctionPointer()`

Comment: Thank you for the updated version - it is just what I needed!